# useContext hook returns undefined

Tags: reactjs, use-context

Inside of App component I have Component1 which has a nested component. I create a contextApi with `React.createContext()` to use it inside of nested component . Using `useContext()` hook I am trying to get `myname` value from `App.js` and use it as style, but it returns `undefined.`
App component

```
      import logo from './logo.svg';
      import './App.css';
      import Component1 from '../src/Component1/Component1'
      import React from 'react'
      export const Theme  = React.createContext();
      function App() {

      const myname = {
       width:'100px',
       height:'100px',
       background:'red'
     }
    return (
<Theme.Provider  value={{myname}}>
  <Component1>
    </Component1> 
</Theme.Provider>
```

);
}

```
   export default App;
```

Component1

```
      import NestedComponent from '../NestedComponent/NestedComponent'
      function Component1 (){
      return <NestedComponent></NestedComponent>
       }
     export default Component1
```

NestedComponent

```
import Theme from '../App'
import {useContext} from 'react'
  export default function  NestedComponent(){
    const mystyle  = useContext(Theme)   //returns undefined
    return  <div style = {mystyle}>  </div>
```

}

Comment: You wrapped myname inside an object, so your context is ```{myname: {width: '100px'}}``` so, just do, ```const { myname } = useContext(Theme);```

Comment: it gives below error   TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'myname' of 'Object(...)(...)' as it is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Inside `Theme.Provider` do this:

```
<Theme.Provider  value={myname}>
```

It will work.
Check [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-tharp-lk01x?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: it is still undefined

Comment: Theme in my code returns  this : App() {
  const myname = {
    background: "red",
    width: "100px",
    height: "100px"
  };
  return /*#__PURE__*/Object(react_jsx_dev_runtime__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__["jsxDEV"])(Theme.Provide… but it should return  calculateChangedBits: null, _currentValue: undefined, _currentValue2: undefined, _threadCount: 0, Provider: Object…}
_calculateChangedBits: null
_currentValue: undefined
_currentValue2: undefined
_threadCount: 0
Provider: Object
Consumer: Object
_currentRenderer: Object
_currentRenderer2: null

Comment: it does not see it as context

Comment: hey, I found out the problem when importing  Theme it should have been import {Theme} from '../App' but i do not understand why

Comment: Because Theme is not a default export from App.js. Only, default exports can be imported without curly braces.